# undefined method `signed_id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

A while back I tried to delete attachments of the active storage so I follow the answer of this question: [Rails 5.2 Active Storage purging/deleting attachements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515529/rails-5-2-active-storage-purging-deleting-attachements)

But after doing this:

```
def delete_image_attachment
  @image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])
  @image.purge
  redirect_to collections_url
end
```

I start getting this error every time I entered a view with images or a link to the destroy method:

[image]

So I change the code a bit:

*routes.rb*

```
match 'vehicles/:id/:image_id' => 'vehicles#delete_image_attachment', :via => :delete, :as => :delete_image_attachment
```

*vehicles_controller.rb*

```
def delete_image_attachment
  @image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:image_id])
  @image.purge
  redirect_back(fallback_location: vehicles_path)
end
```

*in a view that I want to delete some image*

```
<% @vehicle.images.each do |img| %>
  <%= image_tag img %>
  <%= link_to delete_image_attachment_url(@vehicle, img), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

That kind of works for the vehicles that already existed, but when I create a new vehicle the same error appears in every view with an image of that vehicle.

Does anyone knows what kind of error is this, and how can I fix it? 
Also, there is any way to delete all data from active storage, like resetting the table?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe that record doesn't own an image? Try add `if img.attached?` or something like this. Check the docs of ActiveStorage so you can see how to check whether the attachment exist.

Comment: Could you share code where `signed_id` has been used?

Comment: Hi @iGian, to be more simple to explain I've removed some code, but in my original code I check if there is some img or not with that helper method. But thank you for the answer ;)

Comment: @Gabbar that code was used in the vehicle controller, but I swap that `@image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])` by `@image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:image_id])`, like I said in the question. I think that first code destroy something in activestorage table, I dont know...Maybe there is some way to reset the tables, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is the first vehicle 's image attached when creating a vehicle? **|||** For resetting, I never tried!, but maybe from console deleting all rows of `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and `ActiveStorage::Blob`

Comment: I end up dropping the database, I think it is some error with it, I dont know. Thank you for the help. If someone finds out the solution, please answer it ;)