# How to query records that have an ActiveStorage attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Given a model with ActiveStorage

```
class User 
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

I can check whether a single user has an avatar

```
@user.avatar.attached?
```

But how can I return a collection of all users with (or all users without) an attachment?

I tried using `joins` to return all Users with an attachment, but this does not seem to work on either the blob or attachment table, or perhaps I'm not getting the syntax correct.

I'm sure I am overlooking something obvious. Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
User.where(attached_avatar: nil)
```

And if so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Convention for attachment association names

Attachment associations are named using the following convention:

`<NAME OF ATTACHMENT>_attachment`

For example, if you have `has_one_attached :avatar` then the association name will be `avatar_attachment`.

## Querying for Active Storage attachments

Now that you know how attachment associations are named, you can query them by using `joins` as you would any other Active Record association.

For example, given the `User` class below

```
class User
   has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

You can **query for all `User` records that have that attachment** as follows

```
User.joins(:avatar_attachment)
```

This performs an `INNER JOIN` which will only return records which have the attachment.

You can **query for all `User` records that DO NOT have that attachment** like this

```
User.
  left_joins(:avatar_attachment).
  group(:id).
  having("COUNT(active_storage_attachments) = 0")
```

Comment: The having clause of the last query was not working for me. Instead, I used ```User.left_joins(:avatar_attachment).where('active_storage_attachments.id is NULL')```

Comment: ... with pure ActiveRecord DSL of the solution from the commenter before me:
`User.left_joins(:avatar_attachment).where(active_storage_attachments: { id: nil })`

Comment: For multiple images, it's `.left_joins(:avatars_attachments)` (plural on avatars, *and* on attachments)

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to know if a record has any attachments (I had multiple attachments say a passport and other docs for `User`) so I can display/hide a section in UI.

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51179019/5258689) I've been able to add the following method to `ApplicationRecord`:

```
def any_attached?
  ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record_type: model_name.to_s, record_id: id).any?
end
```

Then you can use it like:

```
User.last.any_attached?
#=> true
```

Answer (score 6):

##### Query records WITH attachment:

```rb
User.joins(:avatar_attachment)
```

##### Query records WITHOUT attachment:

```rb
User.includes(:avatar_attachment).where(avatar_attachment: {id: nil})
```

Answer (score 4):

Slightly related, here is how to perform a search query on the attached records:

```
def self.search_name(search)
  with_attached_attachment.
    references(:attachment_attachment).
    where(ActiveStorage::Blob.arel_table[:filename].matches("%#{search}%"))
end
```

You'll just have to update the `with_attached_attachment` and `:attachment_attachment` to reflect your attached model. In my case I have `has_one_attached :attachment`

And for those wondering, the Arel `#matches` does not appear to be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.