# ActiveStorage attachment is present, but showing `nil` in Datagrid column

Tags: datagrid, ruby-on-rails-5

user.rb

```
class User 
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

Inspected the same user in rails console
`@user.avatar.attached?   => true`

but displaying `false` for all users in `datagrid` column.

```
class UserGrid

  scope  do
    User.joins(:avatar_attachment)
  end

  column(:avatar, html: true, header: 'Avatar') do |record|
    if record.avatar.attached?
      concat link_to(
        'image_tag(url_for(record.avatar))',
        record.avatar_url,
        target: '_blank'
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Inspected `record.avatar.attached?` from datagrid column, getting `false`

Requirement: Display all User records that have an attachment and also display `attachment` in grid column.

Issue: As `attachment` is showing `nil`, so unable to display attachment in grid.

Comment: I think User.joins(:avatar_attachment) is a problem.

Comment: referred answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418114/how-to-query-records-that-have-an-activestorage-attachment