# Rails 6: Lookup records that have only have ActiveText attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `User` model that has a

```
has_rich_text :tlk_with_me
```

rich text blob attached.

On one of my pages I want to load all the users with a `tlk_with_me` blob, and none of the other users.

I have tried the solution in this answer:

[How to query records that have an ActiveStorage attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418114/how-to-query-records-that-have-an-activestorage-attachment)

Which suggests doing the following query:

```
@users_with_twm_attached = User.joins(:tlk_with_me_attachment)
```

However I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'User' to association named 'tlk_with_me_attachment'; perhaps you misspelled it?)
```

I am unsure how to proceed. Thank you

Comment: If you post your table structure for users and their associated blobs we can help

Comment: @RockwellRice, https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html the ActionText docs don't suggest adding a column to the table. (see '4 Examples')

Comment: @Mark The User table does not have a relevant column in it (see my answer to Rockwell). If there is a way to get table+blobs, please let me know.

Comment: So, if you output the record, is there a value for `<%= user.tlk_with_me %>` ? You should be able to check on something like `<% if user.tlk_with_me != '' %>`, or something similar, to see if there is a value there.  Or, in your controller something like `users = User.all` and then `@users_with_twm = users.select {|t| user.tlk_with_me != ''}` (I'm not exactly sure if that is the exact check it would depend on what an empty value in the DB looks like)

Comment: Thanks @RockwellRice. I want to display ALL the users who have a tlk_with_me rich text attachment, so I feel like if I work with an enumerable going through all of my users, I'm doing a lot of work if say 5% have a 'tlk_with_me' attachment.

Comment: @RockwellRice ActionText actually works a lot like ActiveStorage. It does not rely on any column on the model itself rather everything is stored on the `action_text_rich_texts` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Association for your case will be `rich_text_tlk_with_me`, thus

```
User.joins(:rich_text_tlk_with_me)
```

(and also probably `.where('action_text_rich_texts.body!=""')` or so)

Comment: Yay, thank you. Can I ask where you found this / how you learnt this as it isn't in the docs?

Comment: Is this where you find out lots of stuff about Rails? I'm always looking to learn more but never checked there.

Comment: @JoshuaESummers “Use the Source, Luk” :)

Comment: Yes sir!  I will do