# comment count with attachment. Use a condition to test whether a record has an active archive attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, rails-activestorage

I'm learning binaries, I have a problem that I've been going crazy about for several days, I created an application with a 2 tables:
post and a child table of comments, in the comments table I have an attached field has_one_attached with active_storage.
I would like to count only the comments that have an attachment and show the count in the Post table displayed on the post index page something like this:

[this is what I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82JTl.png)

```
# models
class Comment< ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :Post
has_one_attached :image
```

in the comment view I can successfully use the following condition

```
# show comment
<% if comment.image.attached? %>

 <%end%>
```

but I can't get this condition to work in the index view of Post I wrote something like this

```
<% if post.comment.image.attached? %>

 <%end%>
```

where am I wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

well after so many days I had to write my first question about stack_overflow to find the solution, and it's also trivial the post maybe it can be useful to others

All I had to do was insert this into my index table:

```
<%= post.comments.joins(:image_attachment).count %>
```

I was missing the convention that uses active_storage or adding _attachment to my image field

```
:image_attachment
```

[this post helped me understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418114/how-to-query-records-that-have-an-activestorage-attachment)

and everything works now