# Click a link to remove an attachment on Active Storage & Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

Has anyone created a form where a user can remove their previously uploaded images from Active Storage and Amazon S3 by clicking a button? I used the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515529/rails-5-2-active-storage-purging-deleting-attachements) as a guide but my app is set up a bit differently. The images are saved as an array (see controller params).

The form renders the delete button and images but when the delete button is clicked I get an error "Couldn't find Space with 'id'=eyJfcmFpbHM..."  and this line in my set_space method is highlighted

```
@space = Space.find(params[:id])
```

Here is the relevant code

The controller

```
class SpacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_space, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]


  def update
    if @space.update(space_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong. Please check your submission and try again."
    end
      redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end


  def delete_image_attachment
    @space_image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])
    @space_image.purge_later
    redirect_to listing_space_path(@space)
  end

  private
    def set_space
      @space = Space.find(params[:id])
    end

    def space_params
        params.require(:space).permit(:space_name, :space_type, :description, space_image: [])
    end

end
```

The view with the delete button/ icon

```
<div>
  <% if @space.image.attached? %>
      <% @space.image.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag image %>
      <span>
        <%= link_to '<- Remove', delete_image_attachment_space_url(image.signed_id),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :spaces, except: [:edit] do
  member do
    get 'listing'
    delete :delete_image_attachment
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_space` is looking for an id of a **Space** object

The call to `delete_image_attachment` is passing `image.signed_id`, the `id` for the **SpaceImage** object, not the `id` for the **Space** object.

Assuming the navigation has been set up in a standard manner on the **Space** and **SpaceImage** classes, the space object can be found from an image object. So make these changes...

`before_action :set_space, except: [:index, :new, :create, :delete_image_attachment]`

```
def delete_image_attachment
  @space_image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])
  @space_image.purge_later
  redirect_to listing_space_path(@space_image.space)
end
```

That will pass the proper space id to the listing_space_path.